# Draw a graph counting the number of trips per day

Tags: python, datetime, graph, seaborn

**I have to build a graph of the dependence of the number of trips on the day of the year.**

First, let's look at the data:

```
i = 0

for d in data['pickup_datetime']:
    i+=1
    print(d, type(d), sep='    ')
    if (i == 10):
        break
```

```
2016-03-14 17:24:55    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2016-06-12 00:43:35    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2016-01-19 11:35:24    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2016-04-06 19:32:31    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2016-03-26 13:30:55    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2016-01-30 22:01:40    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2016-06-17 22:34:59    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2016-05-21 07:54:58    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2016-05-27 23:12:23    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2016-03-10 21:45:01    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

To draw the desired graph above I want to use **seaborn.countplot**, but I don’t know how to transfer the column data['pickup_datetime'] so that it displays only the day and month, and not all the time.

More info about data:

```
data.info()
```

```
id                    1458644 non-null object
vendor_id             1458644 non-null int64
pickup_datetime       1458644 non-null datetime64[ns]
passenger_count       1458644 non-null int64
pickup_longitude      1458644 non-null float64
pickup_latitude       1458644 non-null float64
dropoff_longitude     1458644 non-null float64
dropoff_latitude      1458644 non-null float64
store_and_fwd_flag    1458644 non-null object
trip_duration         1458644 non-null int64
log_trip_duration     1458644 non-null float64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(5), int64(3), object(2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use the [`pandas.Series.dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) accessor to get day
- [`.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the day and use [`.count()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) and [`.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# set plt parameters
plt.style.use('seaborn')
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (16.0, 10.0)

# data
data = {'DateTime': ['2016-03-14 17:24:55', '2016-06-12 00:43:35', '2016-01-19 11:35:24', '2016-04-06 19:32:31', '2016-03-26 13:30:55', '2016-01-30 22:01:40', '2016-06-17 22:34:59', '2016-05-21 07:54:58', '2016-05-27 23:12:23', '2016-03-10 21:45:01']}

# dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# convert to datetime
df.DateTime = pd.to_datetime(df.DateTime)

# groupby day, count and plot
g = df.groupby(df.DateTime.dt.dayofyear).count().plot.bar()
# plt.xticks(rotation=0)  # if you want to rotate the x-tick labels
```

[image]

### Using `sns.countplot`

```py
sns.countplot(df.DateTime.dt.dayofyear, data=df)
```

[image]

Comment: @MaxAweTery You're welcome. `plt.xticks(rotation=0)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a different column for the year, month and day

```
df = data.copy()
df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.pickup_datetime).year
df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.pickup_datetime).month
df['day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.pickup_datetime).day
```